# Where do/can I go from here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a self taught computer technician, I have always found coding to be interesting and I learned HTML in middle school for basic stuff. I recently graduated from High School and can't afford college, 2 months ago I started self study in hopes of becoming a Web Developer. So far I've learned HTML, CSS, jQuery, and JavaScript. I'm still reading books recommended by friends and websites to solidify my knowledge and skills. I work myself through practices and things like Codecademy[(my profile)](http://www.codecademy.com/lupolupido) and I'm working on [something for a friend](http://projects.joeyanthonysg.com/nenasflowers/contactus.html) (I've only done the contact page (What do you guys think so far? I'm planning on using jQuery on the different pages to put up slideshows of photos. Exciting :) )).

What I came here to ask is what you guys think my next move should be? What should I be studying? Should I look for a job to gain some experience? I'm a bit lost and confused.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Such questions are [not appropriate for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq) and will be [closed](http://bit.ly/18T95z1) or [deleted](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR). Be sure to familiarize yourself with [what type of questions you can or should ask](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc). If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J) or check the [FAQ] and see [About] page for general information.

Comment: "What should I be studying? " - The FAQ of this web site?!

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really have a good, single answer.

Some resources I'd recommend are things like:
https://developers.google.com/edu/ (Python and C++ 'courses' for free)
https://www.coursera.org/ (Actual college courses taught by actual professors, for free)
http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm (a dump of MIT resources that will help you learn)

Above all else, I'd suggest learning Algorithms and Data Structures. You can learn *how* to do things for as long as you want, but it won't get you very far if you don't understand (or comfortably think you understand) *why* things work like they do.